# Display data on the listbox from COM Port

Tags: c#, listbox, serial-port

I've 2 buttons. Button Connect(open com port) & Disconnect(close port). When I click on the connect button, the timer will trigger & display the data on Listbox from the com port every few seconds. When I click disconnect and click connect button again, the data will not be displayed on the Listbox and the timer is not triggered. Why is that so?

Here's my codes:

```
    List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>(125);
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (serialPortN.IsOpen)
            serialPortN.Close();
        try
        {
            {

                serialPortN.PortName = "COM8";
                serialPortN.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPortN.Parity = Parity.None;
                serialPortN.DataBits = 8;
                serialPortN.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                serialPortN.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                serialPortN.ReadTimeout = 500;
            }

            serialPortN.Open();
            label1.Text = "COM8" + " is opened";


            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 5000;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
            timer.Start();

            serialPortN.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceived);


            btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
     void datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        myDelegate d = new myDelegate(update);
        listBox1.Invoke(d, new object[] { });

    }

    public void update()
    {

        while (serialPortN.BytesToRead > 0)
            buffer.Add((byte)serialPortN.ReadByte());
        // Call a routine to process the data.          
        ProcessBuffer(buffer);
     }

  private void ProcessBuffer(List<byte> buffer)
    {
       int numberOfBytesToRead = 125;
        if (buffer.Count >= numberOfBytesToRead)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SPO = {0}, PulseRate = {1}, Time = {2}",
                                                    buffer[43].ToString(),
                                                    buffer[103].ToString(),
                                                    DateTime.Now.ToString()
            ))));

            buffer.RemoveRange(0, numberOfBytesToRead);
        }

    }

   void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        int numberOfBytesToRead = 125;
        if (buffer.Count >= numberOfBytesToRead)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("SPO = {0}, PulseRate = {1}, Time = {2}",
                                                    buffer[43].ToString(),
                                                    buffer[103].ToString(),
                                                    DateTime.Now.ToString()
            ))));
            buffer.RemoveRange(0, numberOfBytesToRead);

        }
```

Thank all!

Comment: Is it safe to say that no Exception occurs btnConnect_Click and with the debugger you've seen that the routine is entered and completes? If so, I'd start trimming things down and see if you can just get the timer working with no serial code.

Comment: Read the Remarks section in the MSDN article for SerialPort.Close()

Comment: Hi Hans, I've read it.. It says: The best practice for any application is to wait for some amount of time after calling the Close method before attempting to call the Open method, as the port may not be closed instantly. So how do I know if the port has closed after I reopen it? As you can see from my codes. I've input the if else statement on the btnConnect.

Comment: The best thing to do is try to open it. If it throws an exception, then it was not long enough. There is really no set time. I've been doing a lot of .NET Serial stuff and sometimes it's available immediately on some machines, sometimes it's 5 to 10 seconds or more.

Comment: Hi, I've got this error after I clic on the connect button again. Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection. on the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

1. First off - Change listbox1.Invoke to this.Invoke in data received.
2. Double check COM Port - If you're using a USB serial device, this can rename itself as you change USB ports and through a reboot.
3. Set timer.AutoReset = true

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ok, I've changed the listbox.invoke to this.invoke. But there's no effect. The COM port is fixed which is COM8. I'm reading it via bluetooth.

Comment: Set a break point in the DataReceived call back. Is it reaching there?

Comment: Yes it reached both function. After clicking on the re-connect again, the timer function is not called. I wonder why..